# Automatically apply a tooltip if content oveflowing

Tags: html, css, reactjs

In React code, I have constant-sized divs with dynamic data rendered in them. Often data is too long and overflows. Is there some way to detect when content is overflowing so that I can conditionally apply a tooltip on the content?

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You can check for `scrollWidth` and `scrollHeight` if those are higher than `clientWidth` and `clientHeight`.

In React.js you should place that in `useLayoutEffect` to give a browser chance to paint that tooltip automatically without jumping effect.

Answer (score 1):

compare the offsetWidth and the width of your div